# Issue getting while inserting data having special chars like \ \n " ' from s3 to redshift from springboot project using COPY command

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

We have java based ETL application developed using spring boot, in the pipeline , we get data from downstream (calling another application endpoint) we transform data from the input file (csv) and copy the transformed output file to s3 and we are inserting data from s3 to redshift using COPY command like this:

`COPY schema_nm.table1
FROM 's3://<bucket_name>/projectNamefolder/output/<file name>'
CREDENTIALS 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/<role_Name>'
REGION 'us-east-1'
TRIMBLANKS
TRUNCATECOLUMNS
ACCEPTANYDATE
ACCEPTINVCHARS
ESCAPE
REMOVEQUOTES
BLANKSASNULL
FILLRECORD
MAXERROR 100
delimiter ''
DATEFORMAT 'auto'
TIMEFORMAT 'auto';`

We have in data some special characters like \n \ " ' with in the data and we want these characters to be inserted in the table along with data. Because of these characters records are dropped or rejected and going to stl_load_errs table. Note that these fields are varchar in the table. Can any one please help with how to make sure we inserted data along with these characters.

tried with options in COPY command like ACCEPTINVCHARS , ESCAPE , REMOVEQUOTES but no luck the records are still rejected.

Comment: Can you share a sample row, with the column you're facing problems with? (you can obfuscate sensitive data)

Comment: @Yankee , Sure, lets say we have description column and value we have is as below.
Description Values are 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n

Comment: we are storing this value in a file in aws-s3 as pipe delimited. in s3 the file which stores has content like this for this column: (which is wrong, \n is treated as next line and also not sure why double quote is appeneded at the end.
Description Values are 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I"
"
"
"
"
"
"

Comment: "
"
"
"
"
"
when I am trying to print the value of this description variable in local in console..just to check ,it is printing as :(without quote , but due to \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n so many blank lines are added up.)
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I

2nd row...
3rd row...
4th row...
i wanted these characters \n \ " ' literally to be just treated as simple text characters (not to be treated as new line , or quote etc) how can we achieve this in java.. Please help with this.

Comment: @Yankee , please read all above 3 messages as one message continues, since we have no of characters limitation here in comment I have to post it as 3 messages

Comment: Sorry couldn't get back to this earlier. You'll need to fix this while transformation itself, store the whole string with double quotes. I've had similar data, which includes code and HTML, and when it was double-quoted, faced no issues in loading it to Redshift (without even using `REMOVEQUOTES` or `ESCAPE`)

Comment: Also, if your string is already double-quoted properly, try running the COPY command without `REMOVEQUOTES` and `ESCAPE`, and see if it works